# NodeJS: Memory usage grows during recursive scrape until crash

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am scraping a bunch of stuff from a GET URL API in NodeJS. I'm looping through the months of the year X a # of cities. I have a scrapeChunk() function that I call once for each instance of the parameters, i.e. {startDate: ..., endDate: ..., location:...}. Inside I do a jsdom parsing of a table, convert to CSV, append the CSV to a file. Inside all of the nested asynchronous callbacks, I finally call the scrapeChunk function again with the next parameters instance.

It all works, but the node instance grows and grows in RAM until I get a "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory" error.

My Question: Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of JavaScript and/or the libraries I'm using? Can I somehow get each task to complete, FREE its memory, and then start the next task? I tried a sequence from FuturesJS and it seems to suffer from the same leak.

Comment: Can you post your algorithm or better yet just give us the order of magnitude of you recursive algorithm and the input size? That would help.

Comment: I am having exact same problem using `request` and scraping recursively. I maybe scrape 20k urls and it throws an error. The thing is the data is only about 1meg worth -- but my guess is the body of the url scraped is not being garbage collected, so after 10k or so I get the out of memory error. That could eat up 4gb of ram I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

What is probably happening is that you're building a very deep call tree, and the upper levels of that  tree keep references to their data around, so it never gets claimed by the garbage collector.

One thing to do is, in your own code, when you call a callback at the end, do that by invoking `process.nextTick();`. That way, the calling function can end and release its variables. Also, make sure you're not piling all your data into a global structure that keeps those references around forever.

Without seeing the code, it's a bit tricky to come up with good responses. But this is not a limitation of node.js or its approach (There are lots of long-running and complex applications out there that use it), but how you make use of it.

Comment: Can you point me to an explanation of this? I am having same problem and can only do 10k requests at a time.

Comment: `process.nextTick()` did the job for me. Really great answer !

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) instead of JSDom. The author claims it is leaner and 8x times faster.

Comment: i have the same problem with cheerio too, although you're right. it is better than jsdom.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your description is correct, I think the cause of the problem is obvious - the recursive call to scrapeChunk(). Dispatch the tasks using a loop (or look into node's stream facilities), and ensure that they actually return.

What's going on here sounds something like this:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... ];
function scrapeCheck(index) {
  // allocate variables, do work, etc, etc
  scrapeCheck(index+1)
}
```

With a long enough list, you are guaranteed to exhaust memory, or stack depth, or the heap, or any number of things, depending on what you do during the function body. What I'd suggest is something like this:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... ];
list.forEach(function scrapeCheck(index) {
  // allocate variables, do work, etc, etc
  return;
});
```

Frustratingly nested callbacks are an orthogonal problem, but I would suggest you take a look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library (in particular [async/waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall)), which is both popular and useful for this class of task.

Comment: Yet, `scrapeCheck` seems to be asynchronous (OP says he tried FutureJS); and a good engine should be able to resolve that tail recursion.

Comment: Being asynchronous tells us nothing about whether or not a function has an optimizable tail call. But the question is moot - Javascript doesn't eliminate tail calls anyway.

Comment: The only reason I'm recursing is because each task does an HTTP request, and then a jsdom parse inside the request callback, which itself might be async (not sure on that). I don't want to dispatch all... ~25,000 HTTP requests at once, nor do I want to do that many jsdom parses at once. I want the async stuff to all finish for the whole task, GC the task stuff, then start the next task. What if I used setTimeout(task) as the recursive call instead of a direct call?

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'd recommend using https://github.com/caolan/async#eachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback to perform the batch-pooled processing of items. Basically, you write a function that pops of an item of the queue, does all the (async) HTTP requests, then calls its callback to indicate that it is finished. `eachLimit` allows you to process multiple requests in parallel. `setTimeout` is not the recommended way as it's a lot slower than node's internal event scheduling options. Also, it does not work in case your requests take a longer.

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the recursive call to your function. Put the recursive call inside a

```
setTimeout(()=>{
recursiveScrapFunHere();
}, 2000);
```

this way the call is asynchronous and gets put inside a priority heap instead of the usual recursion stack (which is the case for synchronous calls).

This way your parent function (the same function) finishes running till the end and the recursiveScrapFunHere() is outside the recursion stack.

Here the call will be made after a delay of 2 seconds.